# What was the Satanic Panic of the 1980s and how did it become connected to RPGs?

Tags: history-of-gaming

Listening to a [podcast episode](https://court-games.pinecast.co/episode/16135c7a/the-history-of-tabletop-rpgs-and-legend-of-the-five-rings) covering the history of [legends-of-the-five-rings](/questions/tagged/legends-of-the-five-rings), the following tidbit was what perked my interest:

When discussing the history of the hobby before the inception of L5R in the 90s, the hosts mentioned the Satanic Panic that would have suppressed the public face of the Hobby to some degree for about 6 years. Now I am piqued:

- What was this Satanic Panic of the 1980s and how did it become connected to the Hobby of RPGs in the first place?

Comment: Related on [What is the background of Christian resistance to roleplaying?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37720/what-is-the-background-of-christian-resistance-to-role-playing)

Comment: This may almost be a dupe of the above, or at least the scope is larger than tRPGs as the Satanic Panic was not solely about them and was a larger cultural phenomenon.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov while related, the two are about different times (~2004-2008 in case of the other question) and this is more towards the impact it had, for example D&D being pulled from Toys R Us where it had been stocked only a couple years prior.

Comment: @Trish That linked question is *not* about a specific time. It uses that reference as a starting point and asks for a broad history, and the answers given seem to cover your question here just fine.

Comment: Yeah that question and its answers directly cover the satanic panic of the 1980s and how it impacted the hobby of RPGs.

Comment: Related: https://www.wired.com/story/the-missing-teen-who-fueled-cult-panic-over-dungeons-and-dragons

Comment: The pod cast is not quite right. *the hosts mentioned the Satanic Panic that would have suppressed any demand for the Hobby for about 6 years* RPGs were still made and sold during that period, and an analysis done on the economics of TSR show that the controversy had a correlation with increased sales of their flagship game.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it *did* vanish from Toys R Us though and the Cartoon was canceled.

Comment: The presumption that the cartoon was canceled due to the Satanic Panic overlooks some internal issues within TSR at the time. Correlation, not necessarily causation.  And Sullivans toys carried it throughout ...

Comment: @ThomasMarkov with the slight refocus on how the two became interacting, it might be separate.

Comment: @Trish This is the exact same question, and the other one has several high quality, high scoring answers that directly address your question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Prelude to Panic

The groundwork to the 80s panic was probably laid by the 1979 [disappearance of Dallas Egbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Dallas_Egbert_III). A child prodigy with ties to the RPG subculture, unable to fit in, attempted suicide, attempted to run away from home and, a year later, shot himself. He was thought to have played D&D, and that part of the story was what the media focussed on between September 2nd and 14th.

Role-playing games were blamed and the connection was probably fixed in some peoples' minds after a [Tom Hanks movie pushing the same narrative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazes_and_Monsters) entered theaters in December 1982.

Six months prior to the premiere of the film, [Irving Pulling shot himself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_Pulling#Biography), his mother found Role-playing books among his belongings - she had not been previously aware of his hobby.

In 1984, William Dear published his book [The Dungeon Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dungeon_Master), in which he recounted his involvement and search for Dallas Egbert back in 1979.

### National Panic

The next year, the panic started to truly form. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satanic_panic#Conspiracy_theories),

> In 1985, Patricia Pulling joined forces with psychiatrist Thomas Radecki, director of the National Coalition on Television Violence, to create B.A.D.D. (Bothered About Dungeons and Dragons). Pulling and B.A.D.D. saw role-playing games generally and Dungeons & Dragons specifically as Satanic cult recruitment tools, inducing youth to suicide, murder, and Satanic ritual abuse. Other alleged recruitment tools included heavy metal music, educators, child care centers, and television. This information was shared at policing and public awareness seminars on crime and the occult, sometimes by active police officers. None of these allegations held up in analysis or in court. In fact, analysis of youth suicide over the period in question found that players of role-playing games actually had a much lower rate of suicide than the average.

(I have found 1982, 1983, and 1985 as dates for the founding of B.A.D.D., but Radecki seems to have involved himself and lent credence to the idea in 1985; he has since been stripped of his medical license and is currently serving a prison sentence for trading opioids for sex)

Patricia Pulling, having lost her son to suicide, latched onto his RPG hobby as an explanation. Unfortunately, this proved a profitable narrative for the media, just as much as it had been in 1979.

To quote [Gygax on *60 minutes*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yShqF1YSfDs) in 1985,

> There's no link, except perhaps in the mind of those people who are looking desperately for any other cause than their own failures as a parent, for their child's death.

[Here's a retrospective article on the topic](https://web.archive.org/web/20130104131941/http://www.usask.ca/relst/jrpc/art9-roleplaying-print.html), and another on the [Dallas Egbert case](https://www.wired.com/story/the-missing-teen-who-fueled-cult-panic-over-dungeons-and-dragons/).

Comment: The disappearance of Dallas Egbert for about a week in 1979 might have laid groundwork too...

Comment: @Trish Yes, probably. The disappearance both made the hobby grow significantly faster, and made the media aware of it as a (bad) explanation for the troubles of teens.

Comment: @Trish Just as a contrast; Here's a link to a RPG created by the Swedish Church in 1993, for use in Confirmation training: https://svenskakyrkan.se/vasterasstift/app/WebShop/Item/Details/76

Answer (score 2):

The [Satanic Panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satanic_panic) is a moral panic that started in the US in the early 1980s, and has spread to much of the world. The basic claim of the panic is that Satanism is widespread in the world, and people, especially children are subjected to ritual physical and/or sexual abuse. These days, it's most prominent as part of the [QAnon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAnon) collection of conspiracy theories.

Almost any cultural phenomena that weren't part of an idealised Conservative Christian lifestyle were subject to accusations of being recruiting tools for Satanism. Role-playing games in general and Dungeons and Dragons specifically were accused by a [campaign group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satanic_panic#Conspiracy_theories) called B.A.D.D ("Bothered About Dungeons & Dragons"). Other targets included heavy metal music, television, child care centres and educators in general. None of the accusations stood up to examination, but they did prompt TSR to [remove demons and devils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_controversies#TSR_removes_Satanic_monsters) from AD&D2e.