# What was it like growing up through the Dungeons and Dragons moral panic?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

I have heard that in the 1970s and 1980s there were a huge uproar over tabletop RPGs much like how Online game addiction is now. I would like to know what was it like for you growing up in the hysteria of Dungeons and Dragons?

Comment: As fascinating a question as this could no doubt turn into, I'm afraid it'll probably end up closed for being 'off-topic' or 'too broad'.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new here. So I have no idea what the rules or where what question should go where.

Comment: Related: [Best answer for people concerned about RPG activities being occult or dangerous?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/best-answer-for-people-concerned-about-rpg-activities-being-occult-or-dangerous)

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure it's OT, after all it's [tag:rpg-history], which should definitely by IT.

Comment: @Earth001 Welcome! Our [About] is helpful for figuring these things out. This question *probably* doesn't work well in our system since it likely needs broad opinion and discussion to answer well, but that's not a terrible mistake. This site really focuses on questions that might possible have one "best" answer (our voting system fails horribly otherwise). If you can reformulate the question to something like that, we can probably still help. If not, [I can recommend a number of forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3404/321) that are tailored to having longer discussions.

Comment: There's actually a pretty good discussion of this on [/r/rpg](http://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/24nay4/what_was_it_like_during_the_anti_dungeons_and/)

Comment: obligatory link to [Dark Dungeons](http://www.chick.com/READING/TRACTS/0046/0046_01.ASP)

Comment: @Lohoris There are lots of question that are inside the scope of our site topic, but which are outside the scope of the site system.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but RPG.SE is for actionable answers to problems you face - this would be an interesting but not in-scope set of anecdotes. Feel free and check out the help center (link's at the top) to help understand our Q&A format, it's different from a forum in many ways.